# What does ‘just’ mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request

> “The heart is such that doesn’t just obey.”

I want to say that the heart is odd; it continues to demand what it wants. I am trying to entice it, but dosen’t obey me. Does ‘just’ implies here something persistence or  continuance?

Comment: Your example doesn't look like anything a native speaker would ever be likely to say - but if they *did*, the actual word ***just*** would *always and only* imply ***merely, only*** (the heart does other things ***besides*** "obeying", whatever that would be supposed to imply). To be honest, I'm not sure Anglophones in general would often reference "disobedience" on the part of one's metaphoric heart, to explain why we can't always "control our emotions". As a striking example of "poetic imagery" perhaps, but that's not a great way to learn a foreign language.

Comment: FumbleFingers, wow! I think, as you explain, the meaning is better! It is a love story Bollywood movie directed by Mahesh Bhatt and the title written by a famous Hindi /Urdu lyricist Faiz Anwar: Dil Hai Ki Manta Nahin (Literal translation: The Heart Is Such That Doesn’t Just Obey). So many people tried to translate it but theirs don’t fit as the title is very difficult. Here, I could give its orginal sense into English (especially doing word to word).

Comment: I speak 11 Indian languages like their native speakers!

Comment: There's Blaise Pascal's famous line [*The heart has its reasons which reason knows nothing of*.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/559339-the-heart-has-its-reasons-which-reason-knows-nothing-of) But that's as translated from the original French anyway.

Comment: Sir, thank you! That is, the heart acts arbitrarily in love. Lovely! 